# M2 - Translate "We received too many requests for password resets. Please wait and try again later or contact"

Tags: magento2, translate

Where can I find the location to know the exact translation string? I need to translate this sentence "We received too many requests for password resets. Please wait and try again later or contact" to Dutch language.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems is a two string sentence that gets built in these files:

```
vendor/magento/module-security/Model/SecurityChecker/Quantity.php:62:                       
'We received too many requests for password resets. '
vendor/magento/module-security/Model/SecurityChecker/Frequency.php:80:                        
'We received too many requests for password resets. '
vendor/magento/module-security/Model/SecurityChecker/Quantity.php:63:                        
. 'Please wait and try again later or contact %1.',
vendor/magento/module-security/Model/SecurityChecker/Frequency.php:81:                        
. 'Please wait and try again later or contact %1.',
```

The string is formed like this:

```
                throw new SecurityViolationException(
                    __(
                        'We received too many requests for password resets. '
                        . 'Please wait and try again later or contact %1.',
                        $this->securityConfig->getCustomerServiceEmail()
                    )
                );
```

So probably you would have to add it to the translations csv like this: 
**'We received too many requests for password resets. Please wait and try again later or contact %1.'**

Or as two separate strings: 
**'We received too many requests for password resets. '

'Please wait and try again later or contact %1.'**

Comment: I did find those locations also, but what I the correct way to translate them?

Comment: Check the answer now, just updated it

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct one: "We received too many requests for password resets. Please wait and try again later or contact %1."

Answer (score 0):

You Will have to specify the module name at the end of your translation line.

Which in this case is **module,Magento_Security**

So the complete line for your csv file will be :

```
"We received too many requests for password resets. Please wait and try again later or contact %1.","The translated string for the given message %1.",module,Magento_Security
```